# How to filter ETS table without ets:select

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, ets

I have the module where I store some data in ETS table
Now I am trying to filter the data iterating the ETS table but always getting empty [List]. (this one is matching every time - matching('$end_of_table', Acc) -> Acc;)

```
-module(t).
-export([matching/0]).


matching() -> matching(ets:first(auth), []).
matching('$end_of_table', Acc) -> Acc;
matching(Key, Acc) ->
            FromSec = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{2017,1,12}, {11,00,00}}),
            ToSec = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{2017,1,12}, {12,00,00}}), 
    case ets:lookup(auth, Key) of
  [{Login, Pass, TTL, Unix, Unix2}] when Unix2 >= FromSec, Unix2 =< ToSec -> NewAcc = [{Login, Pass, TTL, Unix, Unix2}|Acc],
            N = ets:next(auth, Key),
                    matching(N, NewAcc);
  _ -> N = ets:next(auth, Key),
                    matching(N, Acc)
         end.
```

May be I have created ETS table incorrectly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable names `Unix` and `Unix2` suggest that you're storing Unix timestamps, i.e. the number of seconds elapsed since 1970, but the function `calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds` returns the number of seconds elapsed since the year 0.  (See the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#datetime_to_gregorian_seconds-1).)  Thus your comparison `Unix2 >= FromSec, Unix2 =< ToSec` would always be false.

The calendar module uses the offset `?DAYS_FROM_0_TO_1970 * ?SECONDS_PER_DAY` to convert between the two, with the macros defined as:

```
-define(SECONDS_PER_DAY, 86400).
-define(DAYS_FROM_0_TO_1970, 719528).
```

See for example [the implementation of `calendar:now_to_datetime/1`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-19.2/lib/stdlib/src/calendar.erl#L311-L313).

Comment: Yeap. Just sorted this out. and post the answer. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

the main thing that unixtime and 
calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{2017,1,12}, {11,00,00}}) are different

so it everything matched to matching('$end_of_table', Acc) -> Acc;